# When I am trying to give input the input line trimmed to 88 digits

Tags: c#-3.0

When I run this program for the input of 100 it trimmed the enter lines upto 88 and gives array out of bound exception.i.e. it will take upto 5 these nos. ( 50 33 11 27 19 40 13 27 37 45 40) are not displayed on console window

```
    using System; 
    using System.Numerics;
    class MyClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string worth =Console.ReadLine();
        string[] worthSplit = new string[T];
        int[] worthTransactions = new int[T];
        int sum=0;
        int Q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] Target = new int[Q];
        for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
        {
            Target[i]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (T >= 1 && T <= 100000 && Q >= 1 && Q <= 1000000)
        {
            worthSplit = worth.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
            {
                worthTransactions[i] = Convert.ToInt32(worthSplit[i]);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Q; j++)
            {
                sum = 0;
                int k = 0;
                while (Target[j] > sum && k<T)
                {
                    sum+=worthTransactions[k];
                    k++;
                }
                if (k >= T)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-1");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(k);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

}

```
     Input:


     100
     34 37 28 16 44 36 37 43 50 22 13 28 41 10 14 27 41 27 23 37 12 19 18 30         33 31 13 24 18 36 30 3 23 9 20 18 44 7 12 43 30 24 22 20 35 38 49 25 16 21 14 27 42 31 7 24 13 21 47 32 6 26 35 28 37 6 47 30 14 8 25 46 33 46 15 18 35 15 44 1 38 9 27 29 39 35 4 2 5 50 33 11 27 19 40 13 27 37 45 40 
     90
     2634
     2633
     2632
     2631
     2630
     2629
     2628
     2627
     2626
     2625
     2624
     2623
     2622
     2621
     2620
     2619
     2618
     2617
     2616
     2615
     2614
     2613
     2612
     2611
     2610
     2609
     2608
     2607
     2606
     2605
     2604
     2603
     2602
     2601
     2600
     2599
     2598
     2597
     2596
     2595
     2594
     2593
     2592
     2591
     2590
     2589
     2588
     2587
     2586
     2585
     2584
     2583
     2582
     2581
     2580
     2579
     2578
     2577 
     2576
     2575
     2574
     2573
     2572
     2571
     2570
     2569
     2568
     2567
     2566
     2565
     2564
     2563
```